# Jquery AngularJS router working in Firefox but not in other browsers

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have developed a app which uses both angularjs and jquery versions of mobile and web.

Im facing a peculiar problem where in which the app developed works perfectly in firefox but not in any browsers, please open the below link in firefox you cold see the router linking two files working, but if the same opened in chrome ie or safari it doesnt work

http://plnkr.co/edit/WBqI3X32FVL0RmW3EmbD?p=preview

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Works in chrome. All I could figure out it is to type some text which dislpays below the text box. What is the expected behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things you might want to change

First, in the index.html, you can fill the ng-app value

Then, in the path1.html and path2.html, remove all the html, head and body tags, and mainly remove the ng-controller declaration, as you are declaring it in the routers.

It shouldn't even work in Mozilla as you have your project now, but that browser is quite reluctant to being beaten by mediocre html definitions (learned by personal experience, lol!)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i did that prototype in a hurry, i have modified it, the updated link is given here

http://plnkr.co/edit/MAMALDBMMjVSUHGLTV4P?p=preview

this depicts the problem i mentioned above, this works on firefox but on on any other browsers

the other thing i noticed is, if i remove or comment any of the jquery js files (web or mobile) the router works perfectly but all my page style css disappears

Comment: Just noticed this article where a guy comments about JQMobile and AngularJS integration

http://simonguest.com/2013/04/08/jquery-mobile-and-angularjs-working-together/

Basically two things: load jquery libraries first, and let jquery do all the routing instead of angular